# Grabbing GameScene size from SKSpriteNode class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpoint

I am dragging my `SKSpriteNode` around in Swift. After dragging the sprite I want to return it to its original position. What is the best way to do this? Right now, I am attempting to move it directly back to its designated position(see code). However, I am having trouble grabbing the scene's screen dimensions. With my current running code, it is returning the node more to the bottom left than I want it(I believe it is because I am referencing self). How can I get the scene's size?

I was trying to use `scene.frame.size.width`, but only succeeded with `self.frame`. Using `scene.frame.size.width` returns an `"SKScene? does not have a member 'frame'"`

Here is my current function in my `SKSpriteNode` class file:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch in touches {
        zPosition = 0
        let newPosition = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(scene.frame.size.width) * 0.14 , CGRectGetMidY(scene.frame.size.height) * 0.25)
        removeAllActions()
        let returnSprite = SKAction.moveTo(newPosition, duration: 0.3)
        let dropDown = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 0.2) //Added Drop Effect

        runAction(SKAction.group([returnCard,dropDown]))
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time and bearing with me. I am a newbie.

UPDATE:
I still do not know how to invoke the scene within the sprite node. However, I solved this issue by adding a CGPoint into the init parameter and referencing the location from there.

Comment: Did you check the node's anchor point?, how did you position it in the first place??, if there are fixed position, it might be a better idea to store the position while setting up the scene and then to reuse them in this situations

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I positioned the node in the GameScene. I am trying to reference the view from GameScene in my object.class file that is an extension of SKSpriteNode. I didn't reposition the anchorpoint at anytime, so it should be at (0, 0).

Comment: Thank you. I used your advice to store the location while setting up the scene.

Answer (score 1):

Change `scene.frame.size.width` to `scene.size.width`. `SKScene` has a `size` property. It also has a property for the `view`. Note that `size` is in points. You will need to factor in the scene's `anchorPoint` if you are doing math to generate a location based on the size.

The default anchorPoint is 0, 0, which is the lower left of the view's frame rectangle. Which is why things are "more to the bottom left".

I am assuming why `self.frame` worked is because you are doing that in the `SKView` class.

Comment: Thanks for the quick, informational reply! I am actually calling the touchesEnd/Begin/Moved functions in my object.class file that extends SKSpriteNode to avoid moving my background sprite too. It is working for the most part, except when I am trying to grab the dimensions of the SKView.